# How to separate the state inside a reusable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***Edit: I have tried to personalize the state of each component implementation using a `this.props.id` for each implementation. My objective was hence to ensure each click to impact individually each implementation and not all the implementations, but seems this method fails.***

I have a reusable component for sliders,

In a react component I'm using several of theses sliders's util,

I would that when I click on one of theses sliders only one of these move but they all move to left or right.

currently when I click on the left _ right button of one of theses components all theses components move, so how make that only the one on which I have clicked move?

here the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/kkqy360p73

How separate the state of my reusable component please?

Here how I import my state:

```
import FruitSlideUtil from "~/lib/pizza/FoodSlideUtil/FoodSlideUtil"
import BeverageSlideUtil from "~/lib/pizza/FoodSlideUtil/FoodSlideUtil"
import DessertSlideUtil from "~/lib/pizza/FoodSlideUtil/FoodSlideUtil"
```

Here how I typically implement it in the parent component:

```
<div 
    className={style.slide_container} 
    ref="slideContainer" 
>              
    <div 
        className={style.option_item_container}
    >
        <FruitSlideUtil
            ref="FoodSlideUtil"
            state={fruitSlideState}
            scopeProps={this.state.scopeProps}
            itemSelected={fruitStock}
            optFood={null}
        />
    </div>                                       
</div>
```

here the state of my reusable component:

```
state={
    // scopeProps: this.props.scopeProps,
    ["scopeProps"+this.props.id]: 5,
    // number of items in he slider
    ["totalSliderItem" +this.props.id]:0,
    ["distance"+ this.props.id]:0, // distance between two elements in px
    ["currentPosition"+this.props.id]:0, // current position
    ["updatedTotal" + this.props.id]:0, // total number of elements after adding remaining elements,

    // element remaining outside foodScopeView
    ["remainOutsideLeft" +this.props.id]:0,
    ["remainOutsideRight"+this.props.id]:0
  }
```

here the function that handle the movement in the reusable component:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    // set CSS variable 
    // § call body variable     
    let root= document.body;

    // § update css variable CSS variable --unit-width
    // call metacontainer ref
    let SliderMetaContainer= this.refs.sliderMetaContainer
    // get metacontainer width
    let metaContainerWidth=SliderMetaContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width
    let unitWidth= metaContainerWidth/this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id]
    root.style.setProperty('--unit-width', unitWidth + "px") ;

    // set number of items contained in slider
    let sliderContainer= this.refs.sliderContainer 
    let sliderContainerLength= sliderContainer.childElementCount
    let updatedTotal=sliderContainerLength;
    console.log("updatedTotal, this.state.scopeProps: ", updatedTotal, this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id])

    console.log("initialOutsideRight: ", initialOutsideRight)
    console.log("distance: ", distance)
    let initialOutsideRight= updatedTotal - this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id]


    // get the bounding rectangles
    var div1rect = sliderContainer.children[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var div2rect = sliderContainer.children[1].getBoundingClientRect();

    // get div1's center point
    var div1x = div1rect.left + div1rect.width/2;
    var div1y = div1rect.top + div1rect.height/2;

    // get div2's center point
    var div2x = div2rect.left + div2rect.width/2;
    var div2y = div2rect.top + div2rect.height/2;

    // calculate the distance using the Pythagorean Theorem (a^2 + b^2 = c^2)
    var distanceSquared = Math.pow(div1x - div2x, 2) + Math.pow(div1y - div2y, 2);
    var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceSquared);


    // initialize state after componentDidMount
    this.setState({
      ["totalSliderItem" + this.props.id]:sliderContainerLength,
      ["remainOutsideRight" +this.props.id]: initialOutsideRight,
      ["distance" + this.props.id]:distance,
      ["updatedTotal" +this.props.id]:updatedTotal
    });    
  }



  // when user click a button to move => handleSlideMove()
  handleSlideMove=(direction)=>{
    let cP;
    // go right
    if(direction === 'right'){
      console.log("go toward right")
      cP = this.state["currentPosition" +this.props.id] +  this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id];
      console.log("cP: ", cP)
      if(cP == this.state["updatedTotal" + this.props.id]){
        // this.state.currentPosition = 0 ;
        this.setState( currentState => ({
          ["currentPosition" + this.props.id]:0,
          ["remainOutsideLeft" +this.props.id]:0,
          ["remainOutsideRight" +this.props.id]:currentState["updatedTotal" + this.props.id] - currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id],

        }), () => { 
          document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', 0 + "px");
        });

      }else{

        if(this.state["remainOutsideRight"+ this.props.id] < this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id]){
          cP=this.state["currentPosition" +this.props.id] + this.state["remainOutsideRight" + this.props.id]
          this.setState( currentState =>({
            ["currentPosition" +this.props.id]:cP,
            ["remainOutsideLeft" +this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id] + currentState["remainOutsideRight"+this.props.id],
            // all remain outside right will be used 
            ["remainOutsideRight"+ this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideRight" +this.props.id]-  currentState["remainOutsideRight"+this.props.id],
          }), () => {
            document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', -cP*this.state["distance" +this.props.id] + "px"); 
          });   
        }
        else{
          this.setState(currentState =>({
            ["currentPosition" +this.props.id]:cP,
            ["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id] + currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id],
            // all remain outside right will be used 
            ["remainOutsideRight" + this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideRight"+this.props.id] - currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id],
          }), () => {
            document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', -cP*this.state["distance" + this.props.id] + "px"); 
          });        
        }
      }
    }
    // go left
    else{
      console.log("go toward left")
      cP = this.state["currentPosition" +this.props.id] -  this.state["scopeProps" + this.props.id];
      console.log("this.state.currentPosition,  this.state.scopeProps: ",this.state["currentPosition" +this.props.id],  this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id])
      console.log("this.state.currentPosition -  this.state.scopeProps: ", this.state["currentPosition" +this.props.id] -  this.state["scopeProps" + this.props.id])
      if(this.state["currentPosition" + this.props.id] == 0){
        console.log("this.state.currentPosition == 0: ")

        // this.state.currentPosition = this.state.updatedTotal - scopeProps;
        this.setState(currentState =>({
            ["currentPosition" +this.props.id]:currentState["updatedTotal"+this.props.id] - currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id],
            ["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id]:currentState["updatedTotal"+this.props.id] - currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id],
            ["remainOutsideRight"+this.props.id]:0
          }), 
        () => {
         document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', - this.state["currentPosition"+this.props.id]*this.state["distance"+this.props.id] + "px");
        })

      }else{ 
        console.log("this.state.currentPosition differ than 0")
        console.log(
          "this.state.remainOutsideLeft, this.state.scopeProps: ",
          this.state["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id], this.state["scopeProps"+this.props.id]
        )
        console.log("this.state.remainOutsideleft < this.state.scopeProps: ", this.state["remainOutsideleft"+this.props.id] < this.state["scopeProps"+ this.props.id])
        if(this.state["remainOutsideLeft" + this.props.id] < this.state["scopeProps" +this.props.id]){
          console.log("differ than 0 remain inferior than scope: ")
          cP=this.state["currentPosition"+this.props.id] - this.state["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id]
          this.setState(currentState =>({
            ["currentPosition"+this.props.id]:cP,
            ["remainOutsideLeft" +this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id] - currentState["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id],
            ["remainOutsideRight" +this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideRight"+this.props.id] + currentState["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id]
          }), () => {
            document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', -cP*this.state["distance" +this.props.id] + "px"); 
          });   
        }
        else{
          console.log("differ than 0 remain superior to scope: ")
          this.setState(currentState =>({
            ["currentPosition"+this.props.id]:cP,
            ["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideLeft"+this.props.id] - currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id],
            ["remainOutsideRight" +this.props.id]:currentState["remainOutsideRight" +this.props.id] + currentState["scopeProps"+this.props.id]
          }), () => {
            document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', -cP*this.state["distance"+this.props.id] + "px"); 
          });        
        }    
        // this.setState(currentState => ({currentPosition:cP}), () => {
        //  document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left', -cP*this.state.distance + "px")       
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the component code and functions that change slides?

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington yeah, meanwhile here a sandbox if it cans help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/kkqy360p73

Answer (score 2):

So there's a lot of issues here.  The code is extremely verbose and hard to follow and you are not taking advantage of the features React offers (respectfully, I've never seen the Pythagorean Theorem used in a carousel!). To answer your question, the reason the controls are affecting all the sliders is because you are controlling their position with CSS properties that you are adding to the body in the right/left functions:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--item-left-food', -cP*this.state["distance" +this.props.id] + "px");
```

With React you want to avoid manually manipulating the DOM (or using refs) unless absolutely necessary, you should use the JSX returned *inside* your slider component to add any classes or styles conditionally based on their internal state.  You're declaring 3 instances of identical state in your parent component as a prop called state which is never used, as well as importing the slider component 3 different times with different names.  You should only import it once, pass what props are necessary to change and set the default state or props inside the component itself.

[Here](https://medium.com/@ItsMeDannyZ/build-an-image-slider-with-react-es6-264368de68e4) is an article about building a slider component with React.

Comment: ` I've never seen the Pythagorean Theorem used in a carousel!` lol, yeah that was my special move on this code :p. Okay thanks